# What is the "bright ideas" stat?

Tags: fallout-4

In pip boy, if you look under data > stats > general, and then scroll to the bottom, there is a statistic labeled "bright ideas."

What does it track?

Maybe savant bonuses?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes its the Idiot Savant bonuses.  I just tried it by building a bunch of wooden floors and when it triggered my count went up by one.